# Can't install pythonnet on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python.net

I'm trying to install pythonnet on my ubuntu, but without success.
I tried some ways as:

1. pip install pythonnet

2.pip install git+https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

there is any other way?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ECL8qX/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ECL8qX/pythonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-ECL8qX/pythonnet/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ECL8qX/pythonnet/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-ECL8qX/pythonnet/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    from wheel import bdist_wheel
ImportError: No module named wheel
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Are you going to give us the error output?

Comment: i add the error,

sorry about that.

thanks

Comment: is this on an ARM based machine ?